# get property value and add property into new array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have this data structure

```
[
    {photos: [{name:'abc'}]},
    {photos: [{name:'xyz'}]},
]
```

How can I add name property as photo's sibling like this

```
[
    {photos: [{name:'abc'}], name:'abc'}
    {photos: [{name:'xyz'}], name: 'xyz'},
]
```

Comment: Does the `photos` array always have exactly one element?

Answer (score 1):

Something like that:

```
    var src = [
        {photos: [{name:'abc'}]},
        {photos: [{name:'xyz'}]},
    ]

    var dest = src.map(function (item) {
        return { photos: item.photos, name : item.photos[0].name} 
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
x = [
    {photos: [{name:'abc'}]},
    {photos: [{name:'xyz'}]},
]

x[0].name = "abc"

console.log(x)

OP:- [
    {photos: [{name:'abc'}], name:'abc'}
    {photos: [{name:'xyz'}]},
]
```

Since this is an example I am just posting a way to add the name attribute.
What's happening here is that since x is an array of json objects, it is simple to add attributes to the json object via x[0]